# ContentResolver.notifyChange not working

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I wanted to play with a ContentProvider example but I ran into an issue I can't seem to solve.

This example consists of an `Activity`:

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    final Uri CONTACT_URI = Uri.parse("content://zulfigarov.com.trainingprj.MyContactsProvider/contacts");

    final String CONTACT_NAME = "name";
    final String CONTACT_EMAIL = "email";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTACT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = {"name", "email"};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter
                = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, from, to, 0);

        ListView lvContact = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
        lvContact.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClickInsert(View view)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CONTACT_NAME, "name 4");
        cv.put(CONTACT_EMAIL, "email 4");
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(CONTACT_URI, cv);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "insert, result Uri: " + newUri.toString());
    }

    public void onClickUpdate(View view)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CONTACT_NAME, "name 5");
        cv.put(CONTACT_EMAIL, "email 5");
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTACT_URI, 2);
        int cnt = getContentResolver().update(uri, cv, null, null);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "update, count = " + cnt);
    }

    public void onClickDelete(View view)
    {
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTACT_URI, 3);
        int cnt = getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "delete, count = " + cnt);
    }

    public void onClickError(View view)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://zulfigarov.com.trainingprj.MyContentProvider/phones");

        try
        {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + ex.getClass() + ", " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

and a `ContentProvider`:

```
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyContactsProvider extends ContentProvider
{

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    static final String CONTACT_TABLE = "contacts";

    static final String CONTACT_ID = "_id";
    static final String CONTACT_NAME = "name";
    static final String CONTACT_EMAIL = "email";

    static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + CONTACT_TABLE + "("
                                     + CONTACT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                                     + CONTACT_NAME + " TEXT, "
                                     + CONTACT_EMAIL + " TEXT" + ");";

    static final String AUTHORITY = "zulfigarov.com.trainingprj.MyContactsProvider";

    static final String CONTACT_PATH = "contacts";

    public static final Uri CONTACT_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + CONTACT_PATH);

    static final String CONTACT_CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + AUTHORITY + "." + CONTACT_PATH;

    static final String CONTACT_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd." + AUTHORITY + "." + CONTACT_PATH;


    static final int URI_CONTACTS = 1;

    static final int URI_CONTACTS_ID = 2;

    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    static
    {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CONTACT_PATH, URI_CONTACTS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, CONTACT_PATH + "/#", URI_CONTACTS_ID);
    }

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate()
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate provider");
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"query, " + uri.toString());

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
        {
            case URI_CONTACTS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "URI_CONTACTS");
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder))
                {
                    sortOrder = CONTACT_NAME + " ASC";
                }
                break;

            case URI_CONTACTS_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "URI_CONTACTS_ID");

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection))
                    selection = CONTACT_ID + " = " + id;
                else
                    selection = selection + " AND " + CONTACT_ID + " = " + id;
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: " + uri);
        }

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(CONTACT_TABLE, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),CONTACT_CONTENT_URI);

        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getTYpe, " + uri.toString());
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
        {
            case URI_CONTACTS:
                return CONTACT_CONTENT_TYPE;
            case URI_CONTACTS_ID:
                return CONTACT_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insert, " + uri.toString());

        if(uriMatcher.match(uri) != URI_CONTACTS)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: " + uri);

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long rowID = db.insert(CONTACT_TABLE, null, values);
        Uri resultUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTACT_CONTENT_URI, rowID);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultUri, null);

        return resultUri;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
    {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"delete, " + uri.toString());
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
        {
            case URI_CONTACTS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"URI_CONTACTS");
                break;

            case URI_CONTACTS_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"URI_CONTACTS_ID, " + id);
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(selection))
                {
                    selection = CONTACT_ID + " = " + id;
                }
                else
                {
                    selection = selection + " AND " + CONTACT_ID + " = " + id;
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: " + uri);
        }

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int cnt = db.delete(CONTACT_TABLE, selection, selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        return cnt;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"update, " + uri.toString());

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
        {
            case URI_CONTACTS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"URI_CONTACTS");
                break;
            case URI_CONTACTS_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "URI_CONTACTS_ID");
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(selection))
                {
                    selection = CONTACT_ID;
                }
                else
                {
                    selection = selection + " AND " + CONTACT_ID + " = " + id;
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: " + uri);
        }
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int cnt = db.update(CONTACT_TABLE, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        return cnt;
    }

    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        public DBHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                cv.put(CONTACT_NAME, "name " + i);
                cv.put(CONTACT_EMAIL, "email " + i);
                db.insert(CONTACT_TABLE, null, cv);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The touble is that when I click on the buttons (firing `onClickInsert`, `onClickUpdate` etc. methods in `MainActivity`) it updates the data in database but doesn't update the `ListView` on an activity. Looks like

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultUri, null);
```

is not working properly. So I can't find where i'm wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for putting a lot of detail into your question and including code examples. When you say it's not working properly, what do you mean? Is it firing an error, or nothing at all?

Comment: It's good to see code and detail on a first question! Please provide us with the detail of what "not working properly" looks like - is it throwing an Exception?  Or not doing what you expect (in which case tell us what you expect and what it's doing).

Comment: Thanks for your greeting). Look at the text in the end of the question (after the **MyContentProvider** code).

The trouble is that ListView which is filled from content provider is not changing on **notifyChange()**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `CursorLoaders` to load the data and populate the ListView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Then use `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultUri, null);` when you insert, update or delete!

Without CursorLoaders you will have to use `ContentObservers`

So, although DB is updated in background and you are using `notifyChange()` but no one is listening to that!

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` (after the onClickInsert) in order to make your ListView notice about the change.

Comment: Yes, it's a common practice with ListView, but  I thought that it's redundant when using ContentProvider, because **notifyChange()** does something similar automatically